# Why are my citations from markdown not converted into footnotes?

Tags: citing, footnotes, markdown

I can not get citations from markdown to work the way they are apparently supposed to work. They end up remaining just inline in square beackets in the output PDF. I am using TexMaker These are my files:
.tex:

```
\documentclass{book}
\title{title}
\author{author}
\date{September 2021}
\usepackage{markdown}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{202F}{\,}
\begin{document}
\markdownInput{test.md}
\end{document}
```

test.md

```
Ich bekomme weder diese, noch diese Anführungszeichen in Guillemets umgewandelt.
Meine Zitate funktionieren auch nicht richtig.[^Siehe dieses Klammer]
Auch dieses Zitatformat löst das Problem nicht.^[Andere Reihenfolge]
Sonderzeichen grad: 15°C
```

The square brackets just stay right there, inline. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  enable the pandoc inline footnote syntax extension, and use `^[...]` instead of `[^ ...]` (see the example). Or you can enable `foonotes=true`, **and** then use  `[^ label]` within the text **and**   `[^ label]: Your footnote.` after the paragraph.

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[a6paper]{book}
\usepackage[tmargin=3cm,bmargin=8cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[inlineFootnotes=true]{markdown}
\begin{document}
\begin{markdown}
Ich bekomme weder diese, *noch* diese Anführungszeichen in Guillemets umgewandelt.
Meine Zitate funktionieren auch nicht richtig.^[Siehe dieses Klammer]
Auch dieses Zitatformat löst das Problem nicht.^[Andere Reihenfolge]
Sonderzeichen grad: 15°C
\end{markdown}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you happen to know why the markdown standard `[^` does not work out of the box?

Comment: @fertchen (1) afaik,  inline footnotes are not a standard feature (and consequently, not enabled by default), so the syntax depend on the markdown flavor:  `^[`  in multimarkdown, `^[ ` for pandoc, rmarkdown, etc. In this case, you must use the second. (2) Note that  `[^` syntax  works but in normal footnotes, i.e., some like `[^foo]`  within the text **and**  then  after the paragraph, in a new line,  `[^foo]:  Siehe dieses Klammer`.